# Check if input value is one or another value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code that doesn't work

```
if( $.trim($('#v5121').val()).length<1 ) {
    $('#v5121').addClass('error');
$('#v5121').effect("shake", { times:1 }, 20);
error++;
}
    else {
         if (isNaN( $('#v5121').val() )) {
            $('#v5121').addClass('error');
            $('#v5121').effect("shake", { times:1 }, 20);
            error++;
        } 
        else {
            if( parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 100 || parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 108 ) {
                $('#v5121').addClass('error');
                $('#v5121').effect("shake", { times:1 }, 20);
                error++;
            }
            else {
                $('#v5121').addClass('valid');
            }
        }
    }
```

If I enter 100 or 108 it still gives me an error (I have tried with parseInt too).

If instead of

```
if( parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 100 || parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 108 )
```

I use

```
if( parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 100 )
```

and in the input box I add 100 it give me a valid class and works. If I enter anything but 100 it give me an error as it should. The same thing goes if I use

```
if( parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 108 )
```

I gives an error if I enter anything but 108, but not when I enter 108.

When I try to do check if the value is 100 or 108 it gives an error no matter what value I enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 100 || parseFloat($('#v5121').val()) != 108 )
```

is always true. If the input must not be 100 or 108, use AND (&&) instead of OR (||). Also consider setting the value in a variable before the check.

```
var tempValue=parseFloat($('#v5121').val());
if(tempValue != 100 && tempValue != 108 )
```

Comment: If you don't mind a suggestion, I recommend you set `var myInput=$('#v5121');` at the top of the code, then use that variable everywhere instead of that `$('#v5121')`. For example `myInput.addClass('error');`. The code will run faster when jquery doesn't have to find that same element over and over again.

Comment: Thanks diynevala, will take that into consideration